# Nutch 2.3 not generate/crawling

Tags: java, apache, web-crawler, nutch

I am new to Nutch. I have installed Nutch 2.3 and have got it working up until injecting the seed urls ($NUTCH_ROOT/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject file:///path/to/seed/).

When I do the next command:
**$NUTCH_ROOT/runtime/local/bin/nutch generate -topN 10**
I get this error:

```
GeneratorJob: starting at 2016-02-09 23:31:01
GeneratorJob: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
GeneratorJob: starting
GeneratorJob: filtering: true
GeneratorJob: normalizing: true
GeneratorJob: topN: 10
GeneratorJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=apache-nutch-2.3.1.jar, jobid=job_local1073670973_0001
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:120)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:227)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.generate(GeneratorJob.java:256)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.main(GeneratorJob.java:330)
```

Any suggestions on where to go from here or what to look for?

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your logs suggest that you are running a nutch 2.3.1 version and you said that you have a 2.3 version.

The 2.3.1 version added a lot of new compatibilities with the others technologies (see [release notes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10680&version=12329371)).

Maybe you use 2 incompatibles version.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your space on the disk for your database ?
Because in nutch 2.X you use an extra database (Hbase, Cassandra...) and maybe you don't have enough space for the data, tempory files or others...